# SQL command in C# doesn't work

Tags: c#, sql, .net, database

I am trying to add new data to the DB table called Users.

```
public string SendUserData(string Name, string Password, string Email)
    {
        SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection("Data Source = " + HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(".") + "\\App_Data\\Database_Users.sdf");
        SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand("INSERT INTO User (Username, Password, Email) VALUES ('" + Name + "' , '" + Password+ "' , '" + Email + "')" , conn );

        conn.Open();

        return cmd.CommandText;
    }
```

It doesn't post anything into the table, any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Commands need to be executed

```
public string SendUserData(string Name, string Password, string Email)
{
    using(SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection("....."))
    using(SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand(@"INSERT INTO User (Username, Password, Email) 
                                 VALUES (@name, @pass, @email)" , conn );
    {
        conn.Open();
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name",  Name);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass",  Password);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email",  EMail);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();  // <- This line inserts the record in the database
    }
    // This line probably is not needed
    return cmd.CommandText;
}
```

Any command should have at least a commandtext and an open connection. At that point you could call one of the execution method provided by the command

- **ExecuteNonQuery**: For INSERT/DELETE/UPDATE or other commands that
  change the schema of the database
- **ExecuteScalar**: To retrieve a single value from an SQL statement
  (COUNT SUM etc...)
- **ExecuteReader**: To get a DataReader that allows to retrieve 
  rows of data from a SELECT statement

[At this link a tutorial about the usage of SqlCommand](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet/Lesson03)
(or any kind of derived DbCommand class like SqlCeCommand)

Notice also that the connection and the command should be enclosed in a using statement to be sure to close and dispose the objects when they are no more needed also in case of exceptions

Finally, do not use string concatenation to build a command text. Use always a parameterized query to avoid sql injections attacks and parsing problem with quotes in string. decimal separators or date formats

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is incomplete. You have to execute the command and it's a good practice to close the connection if it's not needed anymore.

```
    public string SendUserData(string Name, string Password, string Email)
    {
        SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection("Data Source = " + HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(".") + "\\App_Data\\Database_Users.sdf");
        SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand("INSERT INTO User (Username, Password, Email) VALUES ('" + Name + "' , '" + Password + "' , '" + Email + "')", conn);

        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
        return cmd.CommandText;
    }
```