# How to solve a C# & SQL Server connection problem ? Data is not begin saved

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm having trouble with a SQL Server connection in C#.

My program is simple, input a name and a description, then save it with Active Record in a database. But the data is not begin saved.

When I consult the SQL Server database (`Select top 1000 rows`), nothing is showing.

What part of the code is not working, the C# or the SQL? I'm using a console command for the inputs.

My class `Neighborhood`:

```
private string name;
private string description;

public string Name { get { return name; } set { name = value; } }
public string Description { get { return description; } set { description = value; } }

public Neighborhood(string name, string description)
{
    this.Name = name;
    this.Description = description;
}

public Neighborhood(){}

public bool Save()
{
    bool retor = false;
    string strCon = "Data Source=FACUNDO\\USARESTESQLSERVE; Initial Catalog = TestDB; Integrated Security = SSPI; ";

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strCon);

    string insert = "INSERT INTO Neighborhood (Name, Description) VALUES (@nom, @desc);";

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(insert, con);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nam", this.Name);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@desc", this.Description);

    try
    {
         con.Open();
         retor = true;
    }
    catch
    {
         retor = false;
         throw;
    }
    finally
    {
         if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open) 
              con.Close();
    }

    return retor;
}
```

And this is the SQL code

```
CREATE DATABASE TestDB

USE TestDB

CREATE TABLE Neighborhood 
(
    Name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    Description VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Neighborhood PRIMARY KEY (Name) 
)
```

Comment: Where are you running the `SqlCommand`?

Comment: what's the error you're getting? what have you tried? help us help you

Comment: in mssql. whit a sql server express

Comment: A typo and a command that never gets executed.

Comment: The erros is that the DataBase is empty and the save is not working. i run the program 10 times and the name and descriptions are not saving into the database

Comment: @FacundoFonseca You have a typo and a command that never gets executed.

Comment: use this example I think its helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13573380/inserting-values-into-a-sql-server-database-using-ado-net-via-c-sharp

Comment: I would start with not using [AddWithValue](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: Must be a duplicate for forgot "ExecuteNonQuery"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL command in C# doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25030899/sql-command-in-c-sharp-doesnt-work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo here, the correct is @nom:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nom", this.Name);
```

You just forgot to execute the query with `command.ExecuteNonQuery();`:

```
try
{
   con.Open();

   // execute the query command
   command.ExecuteNonQuery(); 

   retor = true;
}
catch    
{
    retor = false;
    throw;
}
finally 
{
   if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open) 
       con.Close();
}

return retor;
```